# How to select each first byte from bytes array

Tags: arrays, linq, unicode, byte

I have bytes array ( Unicode character in this case). Unicode characters consist of 2 bytes and I want get each first byte. 
Linq would be appreciated.

Example:

```
Dim b_1() As Byte = New Byte() {208,16,32,0,49,0,122,0,32,0}
```

Result must be array `{208,32,49,122,32}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it sounds like this is a bad idea in general. You haven't said *why* you want to do this, but it sounds like a recipe for data loss. If you've got data which is inherently text, you'd be better off with it as a string to start with. However...

... you can get "every other byte" by using the [`Where` overload which takes an index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb549418.aspx):

```
var everyOtherByte = allBytes.Where((value, index) => (index & 1) == 0);
```

Use `ToArray` on the end if you need it as an array.

Comment: Thanks Jon. That's it what I want.